# sending email even if adress is invalid, phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form that ask for email address. If the customer does not but an email address in email field example:George in the email field and not george@aol.com I still want it to send the form.
Im assuming its the phpmailer itself and I don't know how to fix it.

is it a setting in class.phpmailer.php that i can change?

```html
<?php

//values to be inserted in database table

$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$phone = $_POST['phone'] ;
$make = $_POST['make'] ;
$model = $_POST['model'] ;
$year = $_POST['year'] ;
$vin = $_POST['vin'] ;
$insurance_company = $_POST['insurance_company'] ;
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?: gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

//cleans the data
$_POST = preg_replace("/[^-,A-Za-z0-9,@,')','(','.' ]/", "",$_POST);


//connect to db

$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');
//MySqli Insert Query
$insert_row = $db->query("INSERT INTO `data`(`name`, `email`, `phone`, `IP`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$phone','$IP')");
$token = $_SESSION['delete_customer_token'];
unset($_SESSION['delete_customer_token']);
session_write_close();

//check if post form was submitted
if(isset($_POST)){

//check if hidden value was used
if(isset($_POST['miles']) && trim($_POST['miles']) !=''){
die('THERE WAS AN ERROR');
}
//implode all the post data and check against bad words in a text file
$my_bad_file = "inc/words.txt"; //make a new file and insert any bad items one per line, Phrases work as well
if(!file_exists($my_bad_file)){
die("Can't find $my_bad_file");
}
$check_content = implode(",", $_POST);
$bad_content_array = array_map('rtrim', file($my_bad_file));
foreach ($bad_content_array as $bad_content) {
$bad_content = strtolower($bad_content);
if (strpos(strtolower($check_content), $bad_content) !== false) {
die('THERE WAS A BAD ERROR');
}}

}









require 'inc/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';



// PHPmailer settings
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->Issmtp(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
$mail->do_debug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = "info@website.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
$mail->FromName = $email;
$mail->SetFrom($email);
$mail->AddAddress('info@website.com');
$mail->Priority = 1;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;   // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true);   // send as HTML
$mail->Subject  =  "company name | Repair Quote"; 
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";



 // defines how message looks in email
$mail->Body="
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<span style='color:red;'>This customer needs a repair quote. Lets not keep him waiting!</span>
<div style='width:750px;text-align:center;'>


<div style='float:;'>
<span style='font-size:px;'><b>Personal Info</b><br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'>---------------<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Full Name: </span>$name<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Phone Number:</span> $phone<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Email:</span> $email<br></span>
</div>
<br>
<div style='float:;'>
<span style='font-size:px;'><b>Vehicle Info</b><br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'>---------------<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vehicle make:</span> $make<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vehicle Model:</span> $model<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Year:</span> $year<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vin:</span> $vin<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Insurance Company:</span> $insurance_company<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Message:</span>$message<br></span>
</div>







</div>
</center>
</body>
</html> 


";




// looks good in your inbox
$mail->From = "$email";
$mail->FromName = "$name"; 
$mail->AddReplyTo("$email","$name");
$mail->SetFrom('$email', '$name');



// gives success or error
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   exit;
} else{
echo '
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://website.com/index.php">

';}
















}


?>
```

Comment: Short-cutting the class's bounds-checking isn't "fixing" it. ;-)

Make the user submit an email.

Comment: some customers don't have emails and im not trying to lose business because of it . all i need is to make sure they have a phone number. if I wanted to validate I would of used a if and else statement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could change the from email and reply to emails to be info@website.com instead of the email the user entered.  Then you know it is always a valid email.  I'm not sure your SMTP will allow a send from an invalid email.

The downside would be that you can't reply directly to the user but would have to copy the email address from the body of the message.  Maybe you could make the email address a mailto: link in the body?

Comment: if a user does not provide and email it defaults info@website.com and using  this $mail->addReplyTo('$email'); will work for the ones that do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic programming thing you're missing - you're just assuming that things will work and not checking return values. If you attempt to use an invalid address in the call to `setFrom`, it will return false, same goes for all the other address-setting functions like `addAddress`.

Don't put the submitter's address in the From address - it will fail SPF checks. Put their address in a reply-to address and put your address as the From address.

You've based your code on an obsolete example - make sure you're using [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and use [the examples provided wtih it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).